# Image and kernel of an embedding function $i(x)=x$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given a subspace $U$ of a linear vector space $V$, find kernel and
> image of the embedding map $i:U \to V$, which acts as an identity
> $i(x)=x$.

What I have already achieved:

**Kernel:** since we need to find $x \in U: \space i(x)=0$, we can simply see that the only solution is when $x=0$. So, $Ker(i)=\mathcal{O}$

**Image:** say that $\dim(U)=1$. Then the image of $i$ is generated by any nonzero vector, say $x=1$. Then $i(x)=1$ and $Im(i)=[1]=U$.

I have doubts about the image because I have chosen the easiest case $\dim(U)=1$. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

The dimension doesn't matter. The image of $i$ is

$$i(U) =\{i(x): x \in U\} = \{x: x \in U\} = U$$

Similarly, the kernel is $$\ker(i) =\{x \in U: i(x) = 0\}= \{x \in U : x = 0\}= \{0\}$$